# How to switch view from appdelegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard

This code from my AppDelegate from my app, which not use storyBoard, and this code switch view normaly -

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        LN_ShowNoteVC *showVC = [[LN_ShowNoteVC alloc] init];
        _iconBage = _iconBage - 1;
        showVC.number = _showP;
        NSLog(@"showVC.number = %i", _showP);
        _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        _window.rootViewController = showVC;
        [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

Now, i rewrite my App with using StoryBoard..... and this code is not working...i get black window

How i can switch view from AppDelegate???

Comment: Why are you creating another instance of UIWindow? Why not use the window object already available in the app delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer)) I Get it) =)

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        LN_ShowNoteVC *showVC = [[LN_ShowNoteVC alloc] init];
        _iconBage = _iconBage - 1;
        showVC.numberPhoto = _showP;
        NSLog(@"showVC.numberPh = %i", _showP);            
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowN"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        _window.rootViewController = vc;
        [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```